# How to access jar file (which contain Java .class as a API) with C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, jar, jvm

I have published my skeleton application as a API (jar file), Then how it use with C# client application (stub application). That mean is there any way to populate or use my skeleton application's DTO etc objects with C#. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use a jar file written in Java, compiled to Java bytecode with .NET?

Comment: Do you want to call java ( jar ) code from C# ?

Comment: JAR file is a ZIP IIRC.. what do you want to do?

Comment: Hi David Stratton, orn, 0A0D ! yes I want to access that jar file's Java classes with C# .Net (or populate #C .Net objects same as java classes)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through IKVM

Here's there page:
http://www.ikvm.net/

IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. It includes the following components:

A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability

http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html

Comment: Holy Bytecode to IL translators, Batman!  I had no idea this existed.  +1 to you!

Comment: Hi bryanmac! As you mention I have generated relevant "dll" file for my jar file as "ikvmc -target:library core-1.0.jar", but when I import and use that "core-1.0.dll" file with C# .Net it will give error as Error 1 The type 'java.io.Serializable.__Interface' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Core, Version=0.46.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58'. D:\Dev\2010\IMC\BusinessService\LabService.cs 23 21 BusinessService (BusinessService\BusinessService), can you please help me if you have any idea, thanks.